# Amending google analytics tracking code in clickonce published html

Tags: clickonce, google-analytics, publish

Has anybody tried this before?

How can i amend the google analytics tracking code .js into the publish.htm via visual studio?
Is there an easy way? For example by using post build events or what?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the google analytics stuff like on any other website it's just plain html.

however, you will not be able to track already installed clickonce applications querying for updates.
and the statistics provided by google will not give you any information about how often the clickonce app was installed.